# How do i get my game to resize with the window

Tags: python, pygame, resize, window-resize, pacman

Im wokring on my own version of Pacman and am currently trying to get the window to resize. i read an answer here :https://reformatcode.com/code/python/pygame-how-do-i-resize-a-surface-and-keep-all-objects-within-proportionate-to-the-new-window-size. but it didnt help me in my case. at the i have 2 screen, screen and fake screen. if i set everything to blit on fake screen they appear but dont update themselces (pacman wont move). if i set them to screen they appear and update but dont resize. any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. btw its still a work on progress

```
import pygame
from Variables import pelletspawns #imports pellet spwans list from different script
from pygame.locals import *


#Initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Pacman")
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((448, 576))    #Creates screen object
fake_screen = screen.copy()

pic = pygame.surface.Surface((50,50))
pic.fill((255,100,100))


clock = pygame.time.Clock()     #Creates clock object
Fin = False


#Declaring Variables
FPS = 60
MoveLeft = pygame.K_LEFT
MoveRight = pygame.K_RIGHT
MoveUp = pygame.K_UP
MoveDown = pygame.K_DOWN

#Load images
PACMAN_MAP = pygame.image.load("images/pacman_map.png").convert_alpha()
PACMANSPRITE = pygame.image.load("images/pacman.png").convert_alpha()

#pacmans class
class SpriteClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        self.image = image
        self.y=y
        self.x=x
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = self.x
        self.rect.top = self.y
        self.rect.width=16
        self.rect.height=16

    #draws Pacman
    def draw(self, surface):
        # blit yourself at your current position

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


    # move pacman 
    def movement(self):
        pressed= pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[MoveUp]:
            self.y -= 2
            print('key pressed')
        if pressed[MoveDown]:
            self.y += 2
            print('key pressed')
        if pressed[MoveLeft]:
            self.x -= 2
            print('key pressed')
        if pressed[MoveRight]:
            self.x += 2
            print('key pressed')
        self.rect.left = self.x
        self.rect.top = self.y
        print(self.x,self.y)


#instances Pacman
Pacman = SpriteClass(PACMANSPRITE, 216 ,416)


#Function to spawn pellets
def SpawnPellets(pelletspawns):
    pelletx=0      #the temp x co-ordinate for the pellet to spawn
    pellety= -8    #the temp y co-ordinate for the pellet to spawn (starts at -ve 0.5(gridscpare) for allignment
    for row in pelletspawns:
        #adds 1 grid space to correctly align spawns
        pellety += 16
        for pellet in row:
            pelletx= 16*pellet
            pelletx -=8
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255, 204, 153), (pelletx, pellety) , 5)


#main game loop
while not Fin:
    #For event is used to close the program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'],RESIZABLE)
            screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fake_screen, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
    #calls movement function
    Pacman.movement()

    #blits pacman map as background
    screen.blit(PACMAN_MAP, (0, 0))

    #draws pacman
    Pacman.draw(screen)
    #Spawns pellets
    SpawnPellets(pelletspawns)

    #draws screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: you have to find out why it doesn't move when you draw on fake screen.

Comment: figured it out and posted an answer just as you commented, thanks for the help though :D @furas

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, i needed to move 
`screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fake_screen, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))`
into the core game loop just above `clock.tick`. i tried this before but ran into a key error as there was no event for `event.dict['size']` to get a size from, so i made a variable in the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop, and then passed that variable where it was asking for `event.dict['size']`. Here is the section of code i changed:

```
#main game loop
while not Fin:
    #For event is used to close the program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            size = event.dict['size']
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,RESIZABLE)


    #calls movement function
    Pacman.movement()

    #blits pacman map as background
    fake_screen.blit(PACMAN_MAP, (0, 0))

    #draws pacman
    Pacman.draw(fake_screen)
    #Spawns pellets
    SpawnPellets(pelletspawns)

    #draws screen
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fake_screen, size), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```